# Check a string for any occurrences of certain character classes

Tags: python, strings, programming-challenge

This is a [warm-up programming exercise](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/string-validators) for learning string methods in Python from HackerRank:

> You are given a string `S`. 
>   Your task is to find if string `S` contains: alphanumeric characters, alphabetical characters, digits, lowercase and uppercase characters.
>
> ### Input Format
>
> Single line containing, string `S`.
>
> ### Constraints
>
> ```
> 0 < len(S) < 1000
> ```
>
> ### Output Format
>
> - In First line, print True if S has alphanumeric character otherwise print False.
> - In Second line, print True if S has alphabetical character otherwise print False.
> - In Third line, print True if S has digits otherwise print False.
> - In Fourth line, print True if S has lowercase character otherwise print False.
> - In Fifth line, print True if S has uppcase character otherwise print False.

My working solution is here:

```
def parse_input():
    string = raw_input()
    return string

def check_string(string):
    check_funs = [str.isalnum,
                  str.isalpha,
                  str.isdigit,
                  str.islower,
                  str.isupper,
                  ]
    return [any(fun(char) for char in string) for fun in check_funs]

def print_output(results):
    for el in results:
        print el

if __name__ == '__main__':
    string = parse_input()
    print_output(check_string(string))
```

Apologies for the lack of docstrings; I think aside from that, I'm PEP8 compliant but please let me know if I missed something.  I'm interested in any and all feedback of course, but in particular:

- I feel like my `check_string()` function isn't very pretty.  What's the preferred syntax for folding a list of class methods into a list comprehension?  I found [a possibly relevant Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7750982/can-pythons-map-function-call-object-member-functions) but couldn't quite make heads or tails of it.  It just doesn't seem right to have to do `str.method` to refer to a function, but then call it with `fun(my_string) for fun in func_list` instead of `my_string.fun() for fun in func_list`. (But that latter bit doesn't work of course.)

What are some better ways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Add another function to simplify your list comprehension**

You can make your code more readable by creating a function to simplify your list comprehension. By defining an additional function like so :

```
def func_on_str(string, func):
    return any(func(char) for char in string)
```

you can rewrite the `return` statement of `check_string` more clearly:

```
return [func_on_str(string, func) for func in check_funcs]
```

(you can see I agree with @SuperBiasedMan that your variable names could be clearer)

**Use getattr() and the code gets shorter but not necessarily more readable**

If you want to run member functions, here's what you can do ignoring [SRP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10620022/example-of-single-responsibility-principle)...it is nice and short. I think it's readable, but others may disagree.

```
check_funcs = ["isalnum",
                  "isalpha",
                  "isdigit",
                  "islower",
                  "isupper",
                  ]

for func in check_funcs:
    print(any(getattr(char, func)() for char in string))
```

That could be your whole `main()` function if you wrote one. Or if you want to keep a separate function for printing you can do:

```
result_list = []
for func in check_funcs:
    result_list.append(any(getattr(char, func)() for char in string))
return result_list
```

or of course you could use a monster list comprehension:

```
   return [any(getattr(char, func)() for char in string) for func in check_funcs]
```

But I am not sure any of these versions are more readable than what you've got already.

Comment: Thanks.  The `getattr` syntax was what I was looking for.  Now that I see it I agree it may not be any better; I guess python is not always as pythonic as one would hope!

Comment: I liked all of the answers but am giving you the bounty since this `getattr` syntax was what I was looking for.  I agree it doesn't make the code much more readable in the end....

Comment: @CurtF. Thank you! Yes I very much agree with your comment that Python is not always as Pythonic as one would expect. But I think I learn the most when I am trying to at least figure out whether a Pythonic solution exists.

Answer (score 4):

I think your way of calling the methods is just fine. Readable and succinct. My problem is with the names `check_funs` and `fun`. Why are we having fun here?

Generally it's best not to use a function or an abbreviation of functions as a name. At the very least, use `func` as a much clearer abbreviation for `function`. Even though it is a somewhat relevant name here, it's not important that they're functions. What matters is what they do or what they're for. I'd cut it down to just `checks` and then `for check in checks`. Even aside from that though, make sure an abbreviation is clear and not just removing letters. If I was asked what `fun` was short for, `function` would be low down on my list. I could only follow in this instance because I knew that you were actually putting functions in the list.

Answer (score 4):

Your code is fine. I don't know what you're so worried about. But there's just some unnecessary stuff. For example:

```
def parse_input():
    string = raw_input()
    return string
```

What is the point of that function? Well, it's basically:

```
parse_input = raw_input
```

Which is to say, just don't have it. Additionally, your list-comprehension is unnecessary:

```
return [any(fun(char) for char in string) for fun in check_funs]
```

That builds up the whole list before we then print them one by one. We don't need the whole list in one go, so we can just return a generator:

```
return (any(...) for fun in check_funs)
```

Or we could just print as we go:

```
for fun in check_funs:
    print any(fun(c) for c in string)
```

Just doing that lets us reduce two completely unnecessary functions into:

```
def process_string(string):
    check_funs = (str.isalnum,
                  str.isalpha,
                  str.isdigit,
                  str.islower,
                  str.isupper,
                  )
    for fun in check_funs:
        print any(fun(char) for char in string)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process_string(raw_input())
```

Refactor when you need to, otherwise you're just overengineering everything. Should the `check_funs` be an argument? What if we need at least 2 to match the func instead of 1? There's so many arbitrary other features we *could* add - so let's worry about those only when they need to.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  I like the idea to make `check_funs` an argument.